# Center an element that is larger than 100%

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having trouble centering an image that's larger than it's parent element. I've set the min-width and min-height to 100% so that the picture will always fill up the parent element.

The visual problem appears when a image doesn't have the proportions of the parent element. The image is getting cropped too much on the right or bottom side.

I guess i could bypass this problem when i just center the images, so the most important part of the picture doesn't get cropped. Is there a way to center the image that's larger than it's parent element? (Without changing the parent element ofc)

I would rather see a css oriented answer instead of javascript because of performance issues when traversing a lot of images in the DOM.

Here's a part of a screenshot of two images contained in a parent http://d.pr/kEcb. The images sizes are ok, but i cannot get them centered

Comment: Have you set the images parent element to overflow:visibile?

Comment: Could you show the problem using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and [http://dummyimage.com/](http://dummyimage.com/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something to this effect.

```
img/div/whatever {
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: **Half of image width**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use overflow property for the parent div
if you want to view the image coming out of the div use visible else use scroll

Comment: I want the image to be cropped, but evenly on the outside edges. Not only on the right and bottom

Comment: then you can try margin-top:-[hegiht of image -height of div] and margin-left:-[width of image-width of div]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest css solution would be to set the image as the background-image of the parent,

with {background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: center center;}

Comment: This solutions centered the image, but it cancels the min-height and min-width, so the images are too small.